# Probabilistic generation of datetimes according to the period of the day

Tags: python, datetime

I intend to generate datetimes of an entire day, with a 5 minute difference between each one, but I would like to do this probabilistically. For example:

- on datetimes between 00:00 and 06:00, there would be a 100%
  probability of generating a datetime; this way, all datetimes would
  be generated (00:00, 00:05, 00:10 ...)
- on datetimes between 06:00 and 08:00, there would be a 75%
  probability of generating a datetime; for example, there would be a
  75% chance that I would generate the 06:05, 06:10 or 06:15 datetime
  ...

... and so the process would continue throughout the day, with other time bands, with different probabilities, but following this same reasoning.

Could anyone say if it is possible to do this, and if so, how to generate this data programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the information of "time bands" in an appropriate format first.
Start with the "cursor" variable at 00:00 of a day.

Use while loop to iterate over increasing "cursor". Increment "cursor" for 5 minutes, and loop while "cursor" is smaller than the next day's 00:00.

In the loop, check the time bands to get the band and the probability for the "cursor". Use random.random() to roll the dice and add the "cursor" to the list accordingly.

Here is my version of the implementation.

https://www.pythonpad.co/pads/2rzmd1hfyrwmehhs/

Comment: Very useful. Thank you.